# changing text when mouse over without using css class

Tags: html, css, mouseover

I'm writing an html for Email use and I need to style the page using only tag's style (no `<style>` or .css or js) .

This is my html line, when mouse over the text's color need to be changed.

```
<td style="width: 120px; font-weight: bold"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/" style="color: #ff9934" target="_blank">Watch</a></td>
```

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: You CAN't do this!

Comment: it's not possible without js or css...

Comment: <td style="width: 120px; font-weight: bold"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/" style="color: #ff9934" onMouseOver="this.style.color='#0F0'"
   onMouseOut="this.style.color='#ff9934'" target="_blank">Watch</a></td>